# Count Arrays containing only zero's without loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count, counting

I use Numpy and have this Array for Example:

```
error:
[[-1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 1. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [-1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [-1.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1. -1.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [-1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

Now I want to count how many of the inner Array contain only zero's, but without writing a loop function.

Is their any possible solution?

---

I know I could use, a loop with `in range(len(error))` iterations and go row by row and check if `np.sum(abs(error[i]))>0` but I want a better solution.

Comment: For "inner arrays" you mean rows? Just sum the absolute value rowwise and the results equal to 0 mean that all elements are 0.

Comment: You have a formula for that?

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use np.bincount(data).

**Here an example:**

```
m = np.array([[0,0,1,2,3,4,0,6]]
data = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: np.bincount(x,minlength=2), axis=1, arr=m)
```

Then just select the one data you want, in your case, data[0]

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
a=np.array([[0.,1.,0.],[-1.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.]])
np.sum(np.abs(a).sum(axis=1)<1e-5)
```

The result is 1, and there is indeed only one row in which all elements are 0. Also, I included `1e-5` as en error term (as your numbers are float and not integers).

In addition, In case your matrix `a` actually consists only of integers that are just written as floats (as in your example), you can also do the following:

```
a=np.array([[0.,1.,0.],[-1.,0.,0.],[0.,0.,0.]])
a=a.astype(int)
len(a)-np.count_nonzero(np.abs(a).sum(axis=1))
```

The result is 1.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach gives you the row indices that have all nonzero:

```
In [25]: arr
Out[25]:
array([[ 0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, -1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0, -1,  0,  0, -1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
```

Then use the `np.where` combining boolean masks and `np.sum`:

```
In [26]: np.where((arr !=  0).sum(axis=1) == 0)
Out[26]: (array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  8, 11, 12, 14, 17]),)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for `all 0.` not `sum==0.` this is what you need:

```
a =  [[1., 0., 1.], [0., 0., 0.], [-1., 0., 1.]]

result = len([item for item in a if set(item)==set([0.])])
```